# Reasons to use a custom 404 page that redirects with code vs a 301 redirect?

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect, search-engines, 404

We are moving a website from Joomla to Mura and some of the pages are going to be located at different URLs.

I can set up 301 redirects in the rules section of the `web.config` file in order to redirect the old URLs to new locations.

However, my boss wants me to create a custom 404 page that will determine the requested url and then redirect to the new one. Both pieces of information would be stored in a database that the custom 404 page will use to to make the correct redirection.

It's a question between doing

```
<rule name="rulename">
      <match url="OLD_URL" />
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="NEW_URL" />
</rule>
```

in the web.config file or,

```
<cfset path = cgi.path_info>
<cfif path eq "OLD_URL">
<cfheader statuscode="301" statustext="Moved permanently">
<cfheader name="Location" value="NEW_URL">
<cfabort>
```

In the header of the custom 404 page in the Coldfusion template. I did check and the Coldfusion redirect does return a 301 status code.

To me it seems like the 301 redirects in the web.config file are the better way to go, is there something I am missing here?

Comment: By "custom 404 page" do you mean a server-side catch-all handler that responds with 301 and 404 status codes? Or do you mean an actual page served with a 404 header?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister The idea would be to write code in Coldfusion on the server side that handles any missing urls and redirects the user that way

Answer (score 3):

> is there something I am missing here?

I think there is.

By using the custom 404 page to check the URL and then *redirect* results in a 301 redirect being returned to the client. The same as when creating the redirect directly in the server config. The client does not see a 404 when a redirect takes place. Only when no redirect occurs (ie. the URL is not in your database lookup) does the custom 404 page *fallback* to returning a default 404 response.

This is a good idea... instead of processing the redirect logic *early*, on *every* request - which can potentially impact the performance of legitimate page requests (if you have 1000s of custom redirects) - you instead process the redirect logic *late* in the request, ie. when you have already determined that the page doesn't exist. This way, your redirect logic has no impact on normal site usage.

If you only have a handful of redirects then it makes no difference performance wise which way you do it. A 301 redirect still occurs in both situations. (Although managing redirects in a database *might* be easier to maintain.) However, once you have 100s, 1000s, 10000s of redirects (due to a site migration) then using a "custom 404" is really the only way to go.

A "custom 404" is perhaps a bit misleading (although that may be how it is implemented, depending on your application/CMS)... what you are really doing is running your redirect logic only once you have determined that the URL does not exist in the current site.

Comment: "depending on your application/CMS" -- you mean the 52% of sites using Apache?   Apache allows code that changes the 404 status in the custom 404 document.

Comment: "By using the custom 404 page to check the URL and then redirect results in a 301 redirect" This is true but only if the redirect is done server-side and not on the actual 404 page itself. When turning a potential 404 into a 301 on the server side, it's more accurate to call the server-side logic a "404 handler" than a "404 page". The approach in your answer is solid so I'm going to give it a point, however the term "404 page" is misleading because you're really making sure the 404 page never actually occurs in the first place.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I wasn't specifically referring to Apache. The Apache 404 `ErrorDocument` won't be relevant to most CMSs - they have their own "custom 404" document. eg. The WordPress `404.php`.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Yes, I agree. Although the term "page" in this context simply refers to the file/document that handles the response, not the response itself. Granted, it is a bit vague - but this (casual) usage is reasonably common I think. The WordPress docs often refer to the "`404.php` page", when it's really a "template". For the "custom 404 _page_ to use the information stored in the database", you could only realistically do this server-side.

Comment: @MrWhite "you could only realistically do this server-side." -> All I'll say is: If the only tool you know is JavaScript really anything is possible, no matter how convoluted or semantically devoid.