# How do I find if any website still links to one of my pages?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, wordpress

not to be confused, I'm not looking for backlinks check. I took over a site that has more than 10.000 redirects inside htaccess file.

Those redirects were made 2 years ago when the website platform was being changed. Now I want to clean up those redirects, but don't wanna lose any "juice" I still might be having from some sites.

Naturally, if I enter any redirect into the address bar it will redirect me to the current location, but how do I check if someone still somewhere is linking to me using the old URL?

I do have ahrefs and SEO powesuite in disposal, however, I can't find a way to find the info that I need.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The important metric is not necessarily whether a website is still linking to your "old" URL, but whether that URL is still receiving any traffic.

Since these redirects have been implemented in `.htaccess` then the only way to reliably check this is your web server's access logs. The log entry will also potentially include the `Referer`, ie. the URL (website) from which the request was made.

> Now I want to clean up those redirects

You might be able to drastically "clean up those redirects" without necessarily removing the redirect. Although this will depend on the old/new URL structures and to some extent how the redirects have currently been implemented.

It might even be easier/quicker/safer to "optimise" the redirect logic, rather than trying to ascertain whether a particular URL (or URL *pattern*) is still receiving traffic so the redirect can be removed (which is presumably what your initial goal was).

---

*Aside:* 10,000 "individual" redirects should never have been implemented in `.htaccess` to begin with. See:

- [Reasons to use a custom 404 page that redirects with code vs a 301 redirect?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/119516/reasons-to-use-a-custom-404-page-that-redirects-with-code-vs-a-301-redirect)

<sup>(I'm sure there have been other related questions asked on this site with regards to 10K+ redirects and custom 404s, although I can't seem to find them?)</sup>

This could also be a way to "clean up" the redirects. By moving them to the WordPress 404 page/response. You could potentially run a script to convert the `.htaccess` redirects to a PHP array or *database* which is then looked up only as required (so not to impact normal site visitors).

Comment: This doesn't answer the exact question. It's a subjective observation that doesn't reflect an answer. The server log returns an IP and logs are not available on all servers, which doesn't help solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could search the log file for http status 301, which indicates a redirect. In Windows PowerShell

`Select-String <filename> -pattern 'HTTP/\d\.\d" 301' | Select -ExpandProperty Line`

does the trick. You could either inspect visually for the referrers, or you can search & replace the 301 code to 200, and feed the file into a weblog analysis software - most of them have a report on referrers.