# Check if old URLs that are redirected are receiving traffic and they are active

Tags: seo, htaccess, redirects, backlinks

So I took over a web with almost 10.000 redirects created in .htaccess file which is ridiculous.
The domain is more than 15 years old.

I want to remove redirects that are no longer needed for the following reasons:

1. There is no incoming traffic from referring domains and pages
2. To eliminate redirect loops generated over the years

So, for example, I have a redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^en/product-catalog/uncategorized$ /en/product-catalog [L,R=301]
```

How do I check if any referring page/domain is still using the old link?

```
/en/product-catalog/uncategorized
```

Or does the new URL is receiving any traffic through the redirect?

I'm using SEO PowerSuite, ahrefs and semrush and none of those tools have an option that would let me check if the old URL lives and send traffic anywhere on the internet.

I also checked the server access log file but it's quite confusing and gives data for the traffic received in the past 24 hours - which is not enough.

How do I find which old URLs are not being used on any domain/website anymore?
How to check do those old URLs receive any traffic?

Comment: How does this differ from your earlier question? https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/141139/how-do-i-find-if-any-website-still-links-to-one-of-my-pages

Comment: @MrWhite Just like on my earlier question, your contribution is equal to zero. You didn't provide specific answer and you were commenting the same things I already wrote inside of the question. Since my question didn't received any useful answer, perhaps I asked in a wrong way. Also, didn't want to edit the question since it has a couple of upvotes. Is this answer more helpful than yours?

Comment: "your contribution is equal to zero" - Oh, thank you very much! Well, that IS the answer so take it or leave it. Check your server's access logs (you didn't mention that in your original question). The fact that your access logs are only seemingly holding the last 24 hours of data is a problem with your server config/host that you would need to resolve. If you had taken action at the time I answered previously then you would have almost 2 full months of logs.

Comment: @MrWhite Unfortunately, the host doesn't support logs with a longer timeframes - that was the first thing I checked. That cannot be changed and I don't control where we host within the organization. It is what it is. FYI, in my previous question you were referencing how I should remove all those redirects and that it's not ok to have them so many - which was the topic of the question in the first place. I'm aware of all the problems. Having that said, server logs doesn't do any good to me, and as it seems, I'll have to somehow manually check each redirected URL with google dork or something..

Comment: You could set up a cron job t download the log daily, and concatenate daily logs into logs covering longer period. Then search for lines with http status code 301 to find the redirects. In Windows PowerShell, Select-String <filename> -pattern 'HTTP/\d\.\d" 301' | Select -ExpandProperty Line does the trick.